# Ссылаться ли на англоязычный Stackoverflow и англоязычные ресурсы?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow

Я активный пользователь StackOverflow EN, решил внести вклад в развитие StackOverflow на родном языке :)

Самый важный вопрос, с которым я столкнулся, но ответа не нашел - в заголовке.

**Пример 1:** Я увидел вопрос, дал на него ответ, однако вижу, что для автора было бы полезно изучить эту тему поглубже и знаю несколько вопросов на SO EN, которые позволили бы ему более полноценно понять эту тему.
То есть, на SO EN часто ответы заканчиваются словами "Я описал два самых удобных подхода...Однако, для Linux *(например)*, Вы также можете использовать *этот подход*, который лучше описан здесь", но "здесь" - это только на SO EN. Избегать ли такого комментария?

**Пример 2:** Я увидел вопрос, ответ на который есть на каком-то популярном англоязычном стороннем ресурсе без перевода (например, на http://dotnetperls.com/). Естественно, что это не будет "link-only answer", я постараюсь полноценно ответить на вопрос, с описанием и примером, но всю статью копировать и переводить смысла нет.
Надо ли добавлять в конце "вообще, вот полезная статья с еще большим количеством информации, но только на английском".

Естественно, что если есть те же статьи на SO RU, сайте с переводом (как MSDN) или есть переведенная статья - вопроса не возникает.
С одной стороны, понятна политика "SO RU - это другой сайт", но с другой стороны человек может владеть английским и эта информация будет крайне полезна для него.

Comment: да, во всяком случае будет полезно

Comment: Кстати, вы можете принять ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Спасибо. Я не принимал ответ, так как это обсуждение. Выбрал ваш ответ как более обширный.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: я как раз имел в виду ответ Qwertiy. )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Да.

- Если вы пишете ответ на основе какого-то источника, хорошим тоном будет дать ссылку на оригинал. (Плюс, этого требует лицензия CC-BY-SA )
- Большинство из нас знает английский в той мере, которая необходима для понимания документации. А код вообще интернационален. Если код хорош и понятен, хоть на японский ссылку давайте!

Comment: ссылки на источник (en.SO) обязательны (см. текст внизу этой страницы). С японским или португальским может google translate (или аналоги) помочь.

Answer (score 24):

## Да.

Даже если автор вопроса английский не знает, кто-то, кому понадобится та же информация вполне может знать.

Comment: автор вопроса может знать английский в объёме достаточном, чтобы использовать решения из предоставленных ссылок, но при этом может более комфортно задать свой вопрос на Stack Overflow на русском (по различным обстоятельствам).

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, самым хорошим вариантом было бы перевести английский ответ. Знание английского языка - это важное качество для специалиста ИТ, но мы всё же не должны относится к тем, кто его не знает, как к людям второго сорта.